# Type assertion using the '<>' is forbidden,use 'as' instead?

Tags: angular, typescript, jasmine, karma-jasmine, angular-unit-test

I have the following test case in my spec,

```
it (should create,()=>{
     const url  = (<jasmine.spy> http.get).calls.args(0)[0]
     expect(url).toBe('/api/get')
});
```

When I run it, I am getting the following lint error.

```
Type assertion using the '<>' is forbidden, use as instead?
```

Can anyone please suggest help.

Comment: `http.get as jasmine.spy` Is what it wants you to do - just do that ?

Answer (score 2):

From [Type Assertion](https://basarat.gitbooks.io/typescript/docs/types/type-assertion.html).

> Type assertions
>
> `as foo` vs. `<foo>`
>
> Originally the syntax that was added was `<foo>`. This is demonstrated below:
>
> ```
> var foo: any;
> var bar = <string> foo; // bar is now of type "string"
> ```
>
> However, there is an ambiguity in the language grammar when using `<foo>` style assertions in JSX:
>
> ```
> var foo = <string>bar;
> </string>
> ```
>
> Therefore it is now recommended that you just use `as foo` for consistency.

So the linter warns about the old syntax.

So in this case, this is in the new syntax:

```
const url  = (http.get as jasmine.spy).calls.args(0)[0]
```

Comment: FYI to people who come here, wondering why this is the case: see [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/296) about JSX support problems and the [fix introducing `as`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3201).