# Why use 'as' instead of type assertion (<>) in Typescript?

Tags: typescript

I get the following warning from my IDE because I am using TSLint.

> Fix: Type assertion using '<>' syntax is forbidden. Use the 'as' syntax instead.

I understand that I should write the following:

```
get myCtrl(): FormControl {
 return this.formGroup.get('myCtrl') as FormControl;
}
```

instead of

```
get myCtrl(): FormControl {
 return <FormControl> this.formGroup.get('myCtrl');
}
```

However, are there any main issues regarding the latter one (not only grammar ambiguity as suggested in [this answer](https://stackoverflow.com/a/57582978/1471485))? I have up to this point always used the latter notation, so I got a bit puzzled of why we have the 'as' keyword in typescript as opposed to just keep using type assertion.

Comment: Because the latter would not work in `.tsx` files (it's similar to JSX syntax)

Comment: The grammar ambiguity is the reason; if you allowed ambiguous grammar, the compiler wouldn't know how to interpret it.  See [this issue](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/issues/296) and the [fix introducing `as`](https://github.com/microsoft/TypeScript/pull/3201).